# Support multiple html syntax for bold plugin in CKEditor

Tags: html, plugins, configuration, ckeditor

In my application, the HTML can come from various sources and I would like to support the three following syntax for bold style :

- b element
- strong element
- span `style='font-weight:bold'` element

The two first syntax are well supported (bold command gets activated when selecting text).
The third one is properly displayed but the bold command does not recognize it (so it cannot be deactivated by the user except by using the remove format).

I tried to configure differently my `CKEditor` using `coreStyles_bold` like :

```
config.coreStyles_bold = { element: 'span', styles: {'font-weight':'bold'}, overrides:'b'};
```

OR

```
config.coreStyles_bold = { element: 'span', styles: {'font-weight':'bold'}, overrides:'strong'};
```

In this case span style='font-weight: bold' is well recognized but strong or b does not work anymore.

So the question is: how to configure `CKEditor` so it can support that three syntaxes at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is: how to configure CKEditor so it can support that three syntaxes at the same time?

You can't configure CKEditor to allow all three tags. The `coreStyles_bold` setting allows specifying single tag which will override two others.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraAllowedContent : 'span{font-weight};strong;b',
    coreStyles_bold : {
        element: 'span',
        styles: { 'font-weight': 'bold' },
        overrides : [ 'b', 'strong' ]
    }
```

Even if you specify `overrides` as empty table, other tags will still get overridden.

Comment: I tried the above code above but it does not work as expected. What it is supposed to do ?

Comment: The code will use `<span style="font-weight:bold;"` as the only editor bold style. If you paste content containing `b` or `strong` tags, they will get changed to `span` elements.